# Free Markdown JS viewer

Tags: software-rec, javascript, markdown

I'd like to use Markdown for documents to be exchanged with a colleague of mine. The ideal workflow would be IMHO editing the source in any plaintext editor while simultaneously viewing it in a browser. The client viewer should be able to redraw the text after each save automatically, and ideally even always switch to the most recent source file (so I don't need to navigate there manually).

It'd be nice if I could (was allowed) modify the viewer a bit, things like using trailing spaces for line breaks are really terrible (I don't see them, my editor strips them, git complains about them, etc.).

I'm interested in a software capable of this and easy to modify, and also in your opinions on the described workflow.

Comment: What operating system are you using? If you use Mac OS X, try [TextMate](http://macromates.com/). Edit the document, and press Ctrl-Option-Command-P to open or refresh the Markdown preview.

Comment: I'm using Linux and Windows. I'm looking for a OS-independent browser-only solution.

Comment: From the point of view of a _humble_ programmer, I think it could be done with a small AJAX application. If I were you, I would post it in [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: If this is to be migrated, please edit your question to be more suited for Stack Overflow. I would like to have a clean and clear question before we migrate.  Once you are finished, go ahead and just flag for moderator attention again and we will make it happen.

Comment: @ATorras: If I were to program it,I'd maybe ask on SO. However, I wanted a sort of out-of-the-box solution and thus I think it's better placed here.

Comment: @Troggy♦: What's wrong with it? I wrote "I'm interested in a software..." instead of "Where can I find a software... ?" so there's no question mark in my question. Other than that, I don't see how to change it, as it states exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The software I was looking for is [markdownj](http://code.google.com/p/markdownj), written in my favorite language and BSD-licensed.